# Understanding inotifywait, pipes and buffers

Tags: bash, pipe, buffer, inotify

I want to monitor every file change in a directory with `inotifywait`. `inotifywait` shall write to a FIFO buffer, which then can be read, leisurely. While experimenting with relatively huge amounts of events I encountered some bottlenecks, which I'd like to understand.

The Changes are always caused by `touch {0000..9999}testfile`. The bottlenecks are in the form of not catching all the file events.

When I redirect `inotifywait`'s output to a file, everything gets logged as it should be.

`inotifywait -q -m ./` writing to the Terminal catches CREATE, OPEN, ATTRIB, CLOSE for about 5000 to 8000 files. I guess the "write to screen" is not fast enough to be non-blocking?

If I pipe to `cat` (`inotifywait... | cat | ... | cat`), I finally get them all, at some point. So I guess the pipes are kind of buffering, but I don't really understand how this works, or even what to look up. Could someone, please explain this?

I also played with a "solution" I found here. Using `pv -q -B 1g` as buffer (also `buffer`).

```
inotifywait -q -m ./ | BUFFER | \
while read line; do
   # Do something with $line or ...
   sleep 1
done
```

How can make sure every file event can be processed? I have a feeling my little play about bash voodoo found some deeper constraints, where I'd like to have more insights into.

Answer (score 3):

If the output of `inotifywait -q -m ./` is not redirected and you're running it in a terminal emulator, the output will go to a pty device. A `pty` device is a form of interprocess communication, a bit like a pipe though with added features to facilitate terminal-like interactions.

At the other end of that pty *"pipe"*, your terminal emulator will read what `inotifywait` writes and render it on the screen. Doing that rendering is complicated and expensive in CPU time.

If your terminal emulator is slower to empty that pipe than `inotifywait` is to fill it  up, then the pty *pipe* will get full. When it is full, like for pipes, the writing process blocks (the `write()` system calls doesn't return) until there's free space again in the *"pipe"*.

With my version of Linux, I find that I can write 19457 bytes to a pty device with nothing reading at the other end before it blocks if I write 1 byte at a time:

```
$ socat -u  'exec:dd bs=1 if=/dev/zero,pty' 'exec:sleep inf,nofork' &
[1] 1247815
$ pkill -USR1 -x dd
19458+0 records in
19457+0 records out
19457 bytes (19 kB, 19 KiB) copied, 14.7165 s, 1.3 kB/s
```

19458 bytes if I write 2 bytes at a time, 19712 if I write 256 bytes at a time, and different values if I put the terminal in raw mode or include newlines in the data I send (as they get transformed to CRLFs).

In any case, I don't think that buffer size is customizable.

`inotifywait` uses the *inotify* API to retrieve that list of events. In the `inotify(7)` man page, you'll find:

> The following interfaces can be used to limit the amount of kernel
> memory consumed by inotify:
>
> - `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events`
>
>   The value in this file is used when an  application  calls
>   inotify_init(2)  to set an upper limit on the number of events that
>   can be queued to the corresponding inotify instance.  Events  in
>   excess  of this limit are dropped, but an IN_Q_OVERFLOW event is
>   always generated.

When `inotifywait` is blocked on the `write()` to standard output, it can't process the events put on that queue by the kernel. If that queue itself gets full, events are discarded.

On my system,

```
$ sysctl fs.inotify.max_queued_events
fs.inotify.max_queued_events = 16384
```

Now, when you do:

```
inotifywait -q -m ./ | cat
```

This time, we have a pipe in between `inotifywait` and `cat` and a pty between `cat` and your terminal emulator.

pipes have a larger buffer than ptys (64KiB by default on Linux, though can be raised on a per-pipe basis up to `fs.pipe-max-size` sysctl value (1MiB by default) using `fcntl(fd, F_SETPIPE_SZ, newsize)`).

So before `inotifywait`'s `write()` blocks, we need to fill up both those buffers. Plus, `cat` will also have read some data in its own reading buffer, and waiting to write it itself.

For each `| cat` you add, you add extra buffering space (at least 64KiB more).

With `pv -q -B 1g`, `pv` will buffer data internally.

Those `cat` and `pv` will be quicker at reading their input than your terminal emulator, because they need to do far less work to process it, but if `inotifywait` is not quick enough to read/decode/format events, some can still be dropped.

To minimize the chance of events being dropped, you can:

- increase `fs.inotify.max_queued_events`
- avoid sending `inotifywait` output to slow consumers or add sufficient buffering if you do
- tune `inotifywait` filters to only select events you're interested in.
- make sure `inotifywait` and the consumers of its output are not given a low priority (no `nice`ing them).